# Find a normal cone using the trace-inner product definition

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $C = \mathbb{S_{n}^{+}}$ be the set of symmetric, positive semi-defnite matrices (which is a closed,convex set).

Given, $$Z = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & 9\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find the normal cone, $N_{C}(Z).$

By definition, $$N_{C}(Z):= \{A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}): A^{T}(B-Z) \leq 0, \forall B \in C\}$$

I am not able to find such $A$ and $B$. Is there a more efficient way to tackle this problem?